# redirect_uri_mismatch the second time I run the login

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3, hwioauthbundle

I am using HWIOAuthBundle to create users via oauth.

The first time I connect everything ok, I create the user and does the redirect properly on the set: `http://localhost/rememberme/web/app_dev.php/login/check-google`

From the second time I connect more with google returns me an error:

```
Error:redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost/rememberme/web/app_dev.php/oauth/connect/service/google did not match a registered redirect URI

cookie_policy_enforce=false
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
response_type=code
access_type=online
redirect_uri=http://localhost/rememberme/web/app_dev.php/oauth/connect/service/google
display=page
client_id= *****
```

It seems that once you are a registered user changes the link of the redirect.

Why does this happen?

Is it possible to solve?

**EDIT**

This is my configuration:

Security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook: "/login/check-facebook"
                google: "/login/check-google"
            login_path:        /login
            failure_path:      /login
            default_target_path: acme_user_default_index
            oauth_user_provider:
                    service: hwi_oauth.user.provider.fosub_bridge
        form_login:
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
            default_target_path: acme_user_default_index
            remember_me: true
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true
        remember_me:
            key: %secret%
            lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
            path: /
            domain: ~
            always_remember_me: true
```

config.yml:

```
hwi_oauth:
connect:
    confirmation: true
firewall_name: main
resource_owners:
    facebook:
        type:                facebook
        client_id:           %oauth.facebook.client_id%
        client_secret:       %oauth.facebook.client_secret%
        scope:         "email"
        infos_url:     "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=username,name,email,picture.type(square)"
        paths:
            email:          email
            profilepicture: picture.data.url
        options:
            display: popup
    google:
        type:   google
        client_id:          %oauth.google.client_id%
        client_secret:      %oauth.google.client_secret%
        scope:              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile"
        paths:
            email:           email
            profilepicture:  picture
fosub:
    username_iterations: 5
    properties:
        facebook: facebookId
        google: googleId
```

Comment: If the redirect URI that you have provided when you created the client ID does not contain app_dev.php, then you will get this error when you try to connect in the dev environment.

Comment: As I wrote above, the redirect on google api has been set as follows: "http://localhost/rememberme/web/app_dev.php/login/check-google".    The strange thing is that it does not always happen! Sometimes it connects regularly.

Comment: You could create an issue in the project of the bundle.
I also encounter the same problem, besides the fact of not having a redirest almost never correct!

Comment: I've got pretty much the exact same issue. Here's the ticket: https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/issues/532

Answer (score 0):

You should add the redirect_uri

to Redirect URIs in [https://console.developers.google.com/project/[your_project_name]/apiui/credential](https://console.developers.google.com/project/%5byour_project_name%5d/apiui/credential)

Comment: can you be more explicit @namnt?

Answer (score 0):

You can put more than one redirect redirect_uri in your google apps credential.
! DO NOT create a new client id !

just edit the settings of your current client and add a redirect_uri below (in the text area) your first one on a new line.

I had the same problem and this fixed it

Answer (score 0):

You have two distincts urls: a first one, defined under oauth.resource_owners in security.yml which is called when the user is not logged and a second one which is called when the user is already logged.

The logic is done in [OAuthUtils->getAuthorizationUrl()](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/0.4/Security/OAuthUtils.php#L109)

Unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to override the redirect url when you are already logged, so you have to add `http://HOST/app[_dev].php/login/service/facebook` as a second "Authorized redirect URIs" in your Google Developer Console.